# F expression not working to update my model in database

Tags: python, django, expression

I have a django model which has a field counter. Every time I am calling the List view, I's like to update this field, incrementing it by one. I am trying to do this with an F expression. According to other questions here and to the django docs, something like this should do the trick:

**My model:**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    skills = models.TextField(blank=False, default="Skills")
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**My view:**

```
class ListJobView(ListView):
    model = Job
    context_object_name = 'jobs'
    template_name = 'list_jobs.html'
    ordering = '-pub_date'
    # paginate_by = 1

    def increment_counter(self):
        count = Job.objects.get_or_create(id=66)
        count.counter = F('counter') + 1
        count.save(update_fields=["counter"])
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Also, I would like to update all of the counters for every job. But         `count = Job.objects.all()` also does not work.

Any suggestions or hints? That would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: But here you imcrement the counter of a `Job` iwth `id=66`, correct?

Comment: exactly. that's what I am trying. I wanted to get this to work first and then think about how to do it for all objects

Comment: you can update all objects with `Job.objects.update(counter=F('counter')+1)`.

Comment: Thank you Willem!! That is great! Yet, also when I try this, nothing happens... Seems like I am doing something else wrong. It looks like my method is not being called at all.... It should be executed every time I visit the list view, right?

Comment: hold on, nothing triggers this method as far as I can tell, you should override the `get` method, etc.

Comment: You are absolutely correct..... With your help I did this like so now: ```def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs): return Job.objects.update(counter=F('counter')+1) ```. It throws me an 'int not iterable' error in my template but I can see in my database that it is incrementing. thank you very much.

Comment: well the `.update` returns an `int`: the number of records updated. So you can first update the records, and then `return Job.objects.all()`.

Comment: Willem, you saved me! Thank you so much brother, it works like a charm!!